# SQL: How to apply unique constrains to two columns where the combination of the two items (orderless) is unique

Tags: sql

I have a table with three columns (`node1 varchar, node2 varchar, other_data int`)

node1 and node2 are nodes that make up an edge for a graph.

So `if node1 = A and node2 = B`, it would be equivalent for `node1 = B and node2 = A`.

Is there a way to ensure duplicate entries could not be created.

For example, if the following is input:

```
node1 = A, node2 = B, other = 123
```

If someone tried to input the following it would fail as the two nodes are already in the table:

```
node1 = B, node2 = A, other = 123
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a trigger that builds a constructed field on the SORTED combination of node1 and node2, and attempts to insert that into a unique index.

Answer (score 1):

I would normally implement this with a `CHECK` constraint such that `node1` always sorts earlier than `node2`:

```
create table T(
  node1 varchar(20) not null,
  node2 varchar(20) not null,
  other_data int null,
  constraint CK_T_node_order CHECK (node1<node2),
  constraint UQ_T_nodes UNIQUE (node1,node2)
)
```

It adds a *small* amount of complexity to `INSERT` but makes enforcing your desired constraint quite easy.

Of course, you haven't said what SQL product your using. If yours doesn't support `CHECK` constraints (Grr. MySQL, I'm looking at you), You'd have to use a trigger to implement the check constraint instead.